# Appserv PHP: Can't find the web page

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, iis

I'm using Chrome. After installing Appserv 2.5.9, browser can't find the webpage.
I looked into C:\AppServ\www there is a file name "*index.php*" in there.

I've ever used ASP.NET before. So I opened IIS Manager and **stopped** its service. 
I also checked "services.msc" and saw that Apache has been **started**
But the browser keep displaying "Page unavailable" nothing works out.

I put in "localhost" for my server name and its port is 80.
I've done many many tries install/uninstall AppServ 2.5.9 start/stop service but the problem still exist.
So I have no idea what's happening. I can't start learning PHP. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Set apache to use another port

Open httpd.conf file in your text editor. Find this line:

```
Listen 80
```

and change it

```
Listen 81
```

After change, save it and restart apache, and surf to localhost:81

Comment: I changed it and restart Apache as you suggested.. but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After guessing around, I unexpectedly found the solution.

--> **Disable AVAST's shields** (Anti Virus program)

I don't know why it blocks connection to my own PC. Putting "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" while Avast is running will not work.

Edit :
For more info on how to fix Avast is blocking localhost : http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=136841.msg1012207#msg1012207